# Make [mvcsitemap] a synonym of [mvcsitemapprovider]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The [mvcsitemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcsitemap) and [mvcsitemapprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcsitemapprovider) tags have the same definition and meaning (although that may be misleading, since they were created by the same user). [mvcsitemapprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcsitemapprovider) has more usage. I suggest that they be made synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all indications are that the tags refer to exactly the same library. They shared much overlap in their usage. Although the tag wikis being the same was not a good indicator because they were both created by the same user at a much later date, all of my research confirmed the validity of your suggestion.

So, this is now done. Better late than never, right?

[mvcsitemapprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcsitemapprovider) is the master tag, as that seems to be the official name of the tool. [mvcsitemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcsitemap) has been merged into that one, and a synonym has been created as well.